# On checkout, customer not directed to receipt page after payment

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, ecommerce

On checkout, customers go thru checkout and successfully purchase orders. The purchase is recorded and processed. But after the users hit submit on the payment step, instead of being taken to the receipt page specified in the `return` parameter, they go to URL of the last checkout step, except this time, the page is completely blank.

- ExpressionEngine 2.7.3
- Express Store 2.2.0

Here is the next checkout tag:

```
{exp:store:checkout form_class="checkout-form" 
    return="orders/receipt/ORDER_HASH" 
    payment_method="AuthorizeNet_AIM"
    error_handling="inline"
    error_delimiters='<span class="help-inline">|</span>'}
```

Troubleshooting Overview:

- Turned on template debugging. No output on erroneous blank screen. Still WSOD.
- Increased error threshold to 4.
- Receipt page accessible through link in Store page of control panel.
- Changed checkout tag to the following:

  ```
  {exp:store:checkout
      form_class="checkout-form"
      return="orders/receipt/ORDER_HASH"
      payment_method="AuthorizeNet_AIM"
      secure="yes"}
  ```
- .htaccess rules do not seem to affect this.
- Used `name="commit"` instead of `name="submit"` for checkout form submission.

---

- ExpressionEngine 2.10.3
- Express Store 2.5.1

A similar issue is occurring with the same symptoms on another site. Same troubleshooting steps followed to no avail.

- Page 1: `{exp:store:checkout form_class="form-inline" next="checkout/2"}`
- Page 2 `{exp:store:checkout require="name|address1|city|country|phone" next="checkout/3"}`
- Page 3 `{exp:store:checkout payment_method="Stripe" return="checkout/receipt/ORDER_HASH"}`

Comment: Turn error reporting all the way, if you're getting a WSOD, then there is a PHP error happening, you're just not seeing it reported because of error reporting levels. Be watchful of add-ons that intervene and override EE's error reporting level.

Comment: Turned up the error threshold to 4 and set it to output to an error log. But nothing related showed up.

Comment: Also try removing your .htaccess file temporarily to see if things are redirecting properly. Its been a while since I have used Authorize.net AIM gateway but I now a few gateways have issues depending on your htaccess file.

Comment: Hi @JustinLong, I added my troubleshooting steps for the htaccess in **EDIT3**